# How to cange value of button overflowText property?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have panel wiht toolbar with buttons. Panel resizable when it small buttons hide in menu. In menu it show icon and value of overflowText. But on click button i need change overflowText.

```
expandClick: function (btn) {
    var me = this;

    btn.blur();
    btn.overflowText = btn.overflowText === "expand" ? "reduce" : "expand";

    view.fireEvent('expandGraph', view);
}
```

in browser's console on breckpoint i see right value but there is no change in interface. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setConfig( name, [value] );
```

try to use this function to set specific initial configs dinamically.
Sometimes the button din't refresh his state if you modify directly the variable

Comment: if (btn.overflowText === 'expand') {
            btn.setConfig('overflowText','reduce');
        } else {
            btn.setConfig('overflowText', 'expand');
        }   -   this dont work too((

Comment: try @Sergey solution after value changing, btn.doLayout()

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh component layout with `doLayout()` method after you change `overflowText` property.

Comment: `view = me.getView();
        if (btn.overflowText === 'expand') {
            btn.setConfig('overflowText', 'reduce');
            view.updateLayout();
        }`

Comment: doLayout() is private

Comment: and red underlined after try execute in browser debug